# Boot failure caused by drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot

Whenever I boot with my slave drive plugged in, I get the message "Reboot and Select proper boot device or Insert boot media in selected boot device"

When I unplug my slave drive (2nd hard drive) the problem is solved, except for the fact that I can't acces the drive!

The hard drive used to work fine.

Maybe it has broken down?

What can I try to get my second drive back on track?

Comment: Is this an old-style hard drive with dip switches allowing you to select between slave/master? I'd check those, to ensure it's not trying to boot from it. Also, check your bios settings, specifically boot priority and boot order to check no-ones altered those too.

Comment: I guess it's not an old-style drive. I supposed wrongly that the boot drive selected was the one I intended. But I can't find the right drive in the list! How do I get boot to show the drive so that I can select it?

Comment: Should I maybe just switch the plugs?

Comment: This is a little unclear to me. Was this "slave" drive installed and working when the problem occurred? Please give us some details about the drive to help us understand better.

Comment: Attach the drive to another computer. Can you boot when it's plugged in (on another PC)? If you can't start PC while the second drive is attached, try any LiveCD/DVD/USB. Can you see the drive?

Comment: @CharlieRB I cannot tell whether it was working on exactly that moment, but it had been working for months before the problem occurred. What details would you like? It's a 1 TB seagate.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry guys. I just had my master and slave switched around all of a sudden. No idea how this came to be. Now the seagate drive is the 2nd drive again and all is good.

Comment: Just for people with the same problem: during startup press F4, or Del or something like that, to get in the BIOS, go to [Boot] tab and set the priorities of the devices as well as which hard drive to use.